# jQueryMobile Scroll to Div after Page Loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jquery Mobile, I'm trying to scroll to an #id towards the middle of the page when the entire page is finished loading. So, when the user gets to the page, the user is at top the top of the page, and then scrolls very quickly to #example.

Using the $mobile.silentScroll, it doesn't seem to be firing at all.

```
$('#page').live( 'pageinit', scrollDown);

function scrollDown() {
    var myDivPos = $('#example').offset().top;
    $.mobile.silentScroll( myDivPos );
}
```

What would be the best way to accomplish a smooth scroll to $('#example') on mobile phone? I've tried the [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin, which works on the desktop version of my mobile site, but not on a mobile device.

Answer (score 11):

Animating is *fully* supported in jQuery Mobile and any mobile device that supports jQuery. that being said, we can catch the offset.top of the example and use it to get the page to scroll.

A working [jsFiddle has been included](http://jsfiddle.net/UtQtk/1/), but the code is minimal and is posted below:

```
$(function(){     
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#example').offset().top
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked nicely, however is there a way to prevent the user from scrolling as the animation is happening?

Comment: @cusejuice IMO it would be better to call .stop() if a manual scroll happens, I personally hate when a ui forces me to scroll somewhere I don't want to.