# jQuery Mobile not allowing to scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I tried using the following code to automatically scroll down the page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });
});
```

I placed this code at the end of the page, it scrolls down with animation and suddenly jumps back to the top. The issue is with jQuery Mobile plugin, and if I disable the jQuery Mobile plugin it stays fine.

Page Link: http://20percents.com/privacy/

Also, I tried something like form action url#id in other page and there comes the same issue it jumps down and jumps up again.

**Update 1**

I also used the following code but still no use

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

Comment: Have you tried binding to one of the page events exposed by jQUery Mobile, such as `pagecontainershow`?

Comment: I tried some in my local machine and couldn't find how to fix this issue

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407394/jquerymobile-scroll-to-div-after-page-loads